# web server very slow, bombarded with php-cgi processes?

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, php, webserver, plesk

I have a Parallel Plesk 11.0.0 with CentOS 6.3. Lately, I've noticed that my web server runs VERY slow (not the norm), CPU average at 80% no matter what kind of traffic, and my top is filled with these:

```
# top
top - 23:46:02 up 13:14,  1 user,  load average: 70.87, 68.98, 66.78
Tasks: 504 total,  77 running, 426 sleeping,   0 stopped,   1 zombie
Cpu(s): 76.7%us, 22.9%sy,  0.0%ni,  0.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.3%si,  0.0%st
Mem:  16431960k total,  9584416k used,  6847544k free,   322880k buffers
Swap:  4194288k total,        0k used,  4194288k free,  3394184k cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
29794 mysql     10 -10 3418m 200m 6592 S 25.5  1.2  16:34.02 mysqld
11166 fstops    20   0  224m  46m 9776 R  8.0  0.3   0:00.27 php-cgi
11149 fstops    20   0  226m  48m 9804 R  7.6  0.3   0:00.30 php-cgi
 9917 fstops    20   0  241m  70m 7744 R  7.3  0.4   0:05.02 php-cgi
11143 fstops    20   0  240m  68m 7684 R  7.3  0.4   0:00.36 php-cgi
11152 fstops    20   0  226m  48m 9804 R  7.3  0.3   0:00.30 php-cgi
11160 fstops    20   0  225m  47m 9788 S  7.3  0.3   0:00.27 php-cgi
11167 fstops    20   0  223m  45m 9772 R  7.3  0.3   0:00.26 php-cgi
11169 fstops    20   0  222m  44m 9752 R  7.3  0.3   0:00.23 php-cgi
11172 fstops    20   0  221m  43m 9720 R  7.3  0.3   0:00.22 php-cgi
11155 fstops    20   0  227m  49m 9780 R  7.0  0.3   0:00.28 php-cgi
11157 fstops    20   0  226m  48m 9804 R  7.0  0.3   0:00.28 php-cgi
11159 fstops    20   0  226m  48m 9804 R  7.0  0.3   0:00.28 php-cgi
11170 fstops    20   0  222m  44m 9728 R  7.0  0.3   0:00.22 php-cgi
```

Will someone please help me troubleshoot the slowness? Thank you in advance, and please tell me what else I need to report.

Answer (score 0):

php-cgi scripts are processing your incoming web requests. Possibly your site  your site got unusual amount of visitors or a kind of DDoS. Check any sort of monitoring/analytics tool you have - at the very least Webalizer or AWstats are given by Plesk.